# How to host Python Web application online?

Tags: python

I have created a Machine Learning Application using Python. I want to host it online so that it can be used from anywhere. What are my best options?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use pythonanywhere.com, lets you run any python code from anywhere, and even host your websites.